# Freelancer moving to Italy

Tags: working-from-home

I am a freelancer in Russia, I work on UpWork and have permanent income.

But I am considering of moving to another country in EU, say, Italy.

I know that there are some companies in other countries that can "hire" you as their employee, but just provide legal status to you in front of government - you move your funds thru their accounts and they "pay" you the salary from your money, taking all the legal questions on them (taxes, other social payments, commissions).

This seems to be the most convenient and legal way to work on your own, but be employed as an employee in the existing company.

I know the company in Poland (Moja Firma), but cannot find the same in other countries.

Could anyone suggest any?

Comment: I'm not in the EU.. but what you describe, with being "hired" and passing funds through a shell company, sounds *a lot* like money laundering.

Comment: Why? If I pay all taxes in that country? I just do not want to establish my own company because it might require a lot of extra paper work.

Comment: I'm not stating it **is** money laundering.. it just has all the tell-tale signs of it... using companies to cover up or hide where the original source of the money is coming from.

Comment: So you find your own clients and invoice them via the shell company? How about deductions for IT equipment, books, conferences, courses? I assume you will not be able to deduct that and have to pay privately?

Comment: What deductions? I work from home on my own laptop. I work with UpWork and can work even from the beach.The only what I want is to pay the taxes in EU and have an ability to live there not 90 days in 6 months but more. I am the only member of my business and I do not want to deal with huge paperwork for a personal company registration. I do not want to do illegal things.

Comment: Deductions for any laptop, books, courses, cellphone, internet connection, business travel and so on

Comment: I am not clear as to what benefit this question would have.

Comment: It sounds like what you're referring into in the UK is called an 'umbrella corporation'. It's an alternative to running your own limited company. Technically you are an employee of the umbrella corporation, they take off their taxes and then pay you a 'salary', but you solicit your own business. It is likely different in other countries though.

Comment: Yes, exactly, thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

In Italy there are special programs for startups that are very interesting, you can obtain a VAT ID and pay 5% of taxes as forfait and you can't deduce expenses (as a sort of balancing system), that for the first 5 years, but you  should definitely talk with an Italian accountant because the matter is complicated.

There are also strict  laws for foreign workers and probably you should need to obtain a work visa too or/and get officially  hired by a company to stay here longer periods.

Talk to an accountant or work counselor in Italy that can guide you and explain all the possibilities. Or maybe call the Russian embassy in Italy and ask for the information that you need to know... probably they can give you some free telephone consultancy.